# Rewrite rules not firing for rules matching multiple instance methods

Tags: haskell

As far as I can tell I wouldn't think it would make any difference that id1 and id2 are from a type class and id1' and id2' are not. I am running "ghc Rewrite" with the latest Haskell Platform (with both GHC version 7.0.4 and now 7.4.1 too), and I expect to1 to also fire.

```
$ ghc Rewrite
[1 of 1] Compiling RewriteProblems  ( Rewrite.hs, Rewrite.o )
Rule fired: rewrite/ez'
Rule fired: rewrite/to1'
Rule fired: rewrite/ez
Rule fired: rewrite/ez
Rule fired: Class op id2
Rule fired: Class op id2
```

the example:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O -ddump-rule-firings #-}
module RewriteProblems where

{-# RULES
"rewrite/ez"    forall a. id1 a = RDUnit
"rewrite/to1"   forall a. id2 (id2 a) = id1 a
"rewrite/ez'"   forall a. id1' a = RDUnit
"rewrite/to1'"  forall a. id2' (id2' a) = id1 a
   #-}

class Ider a where
    id1 :: a -> a
    id2 :: a -> a

data RewriteD = RDUnit

instance Ider RewriteD where
    {-# INLINE[1] id1 #-}
    {-# INLINE[1] id2 #-}
    id1 a = RDUnit
    id2 a = RDUnit

testThing1 :: RewriteD
testThing1 = id1 RDUnit

testThing2 :: RewriteD
testThing2 = id2 (id2 RDUnit)

testThing1' :: RewriteD
testThing1' = id1' RDUnit

testThing2' :: RewriteD
testThing2' = id2' (id2' RDUnit)

{-# INLINE[1] id1' #-}
{-# INLINE[1] id2' #-}
id1' :: RewriteD -> RewriteD
id2' :: RewriteD -> RewriteD
id1' a = RDUnit
id2' a = RDUnit
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(several edits made throughout post with updated information)

In your output, notice the lines `Rule fired: Class op id2`.  These are rules automatically created by GHC for type class instances.  This rule is firing first, so your own rule never gets a chance to match.  If you compile with "-ddump-simpl-iterations", you can check that the Class op rule fires in the first phase, after which your "to1" rule will never match.

Here's a bit of a workaround.  First comment out `testThing1`, `testThing1'`, and `testThing2'` so only `testThing2` is compiled.  This is the only function where "rewrite/to1" can fire, so it isolates the test case you're looking at.  Next add another rule of the form:

```
"rewrite/to_id2'"   forall a. id2 a = id2' a
```

and you'll see this output:

```
$ ghc -c foo.hs
Rule fired: rewrite/to_id2'
Rule fired: rewrite/to_id2'
Rule fired: rewrite/to1'
Rule fired: rewrite/ez
```

The new rule is now firing instead of the class op, which allows `rewrite/to1'` to simplify the expression.  Interestingly, it doesn't matter if the new rule appears above or below `rewrite/to1` in the list of RULES.

I don't know why your `id2 (id2 a)` rule isn't matching whereas `id2 a` does.  It looks like it should match (according to -dverbose-core2core), but it isn't.  I still suspect a GHC precedence bug of some type, although I also see the same behavior with ghc-7.4.1 so it isn't [4397](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4397).

Comment: I just installed the most recent version of GHC -- version 7.4.1 and I get the same output now as I did before. Also, yes, I realize these rules make no difference to output -- I just made this test case to isolate the problem I was getting in a much more complicated example. Also, I believe precedence is actually working correctly here... just looking at the output is really does appear that all of my rules are being attempted before those come up.

Comment: How exactly are you determining that your rules are attempted?  I know of no way to make GHC show either rules that aren't applied, or which rule is used in the case of multiple matches.  The best you can do is check what's actually fired, which is in this case the class op rule.

Comment: If you change the program so the instance method returns something like an error, that is, something different than the `RDUnit` the rewrite rule should leave you with, the optimizer leaves you with the error value in the `testThing2` example. I think this example program was just boiled down a bit too far to most clearly show the problem.

Comment: I don't know, but I can see that GHC has fired all my rules except for the specific one this post is targeted about, and though I can tell only vaguely that I think the rule is being attempted, I also have no indication that it is not attempted, either. The class op rule tells me nothing besides that my rule was not fired and my method wad not short-circuited, which I already have observed. Also, had it been a problem of order and the bug you specified, I would hope that the newer version of GHC would have fixed the problem...

Comment: Anthony, I made the example to demonstrate that the rules would fire in 3 of the 4 permutations of simple vs complex rules and instance vs non-instance methods -- the actual values where there only so everything type-checked.

John L, I only now noticed that you updated your answer. I am a little resistant to use that hack, but it should work. Thanks.

Comment: @Akh - yeah, it's a hack.  Maybe you could file a ghc bug report with this example?

Comment: @Akh Yeah, I just wanted to clarify that your original report does demonstrate what is apparently bug. The fact that everything ends up fine in the example was, in a sense, misleading. I also encourage you to file a bug report as this would really frustrate me if I encountered it in the wild :)