# How do you write rewrite rules for typeclass methods?

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc

Mind the following class:

```
class ListIsomorphic l where
    toList    :: l a -> [a]
    fromList  :: [a] -> l a
```

I also demand that `toList . fromList == id`. How do I write rewrite rules to tell GHC to make that substitution?

Comment: That's actually not "obvious". That's a property you have to explicitly demand. For example, you could have a tree structure that you can convert to a list and that you can also construct from a list, but where this identity doesn't necessarily hold.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Thanks.

Comment: Also, couldn't `l` differ between the `toList` and `fromList` calls?  For example `redBlackTreeToBTree = toList . fromList` where `redBlackTreeToBTree :: RedBlackTree a -> BTree a`.

Comment: Yes, it could. Considering that, I guess the only right answer would be writing a specific rule inside each instance. Is that possible?

Comment: Rules and classes mix in weird ways. Often, the trick is to write a tiny class method that just invokes a function, and then attach the rule to the function.

Comment: @NathanDavis I expect `toList . fromList :: ListIsomorphic l => [a] -> [a]` (which has an ambiguous "middle instance", but only one), so I don't think there can be two different instances involved.

Comment: You're right.  I had the operations flipped in my mind.  I was thinking of `fromList . toList`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a `RULES` pragma to implement this simplification but you have to do [a bit of extra work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9815210/477476) to make sure the generic method rewrite rules don't fire before yours have a chance to:

```
{-# RULES
  "protect toList"   toList = toList';
  "protect fromList" fromList = fromList';
  "fromList/toList"  forall x . fromList' (toList' x) = x; #-}

{-# NOINLINE [0] fromList' #-}
fromList' :: (ListIsomorphic l) => [a] -> l a
fromList' = fromList

{-# NOINLINE [0] toList' #-}
toList' :: (ListIsomorphic l) => l a -> [a]
toList' = toList
```

Here's a silly example to show that it works:

```
instance ListIsomorphic Maybe where
    toList = error "toList"
    fromList = error "fromList"

test1 :: Maybe a -> Maybe a
test1 x = fromList (toList x)

main = print $ test1 $ Just "Hello"
```

This prints `Just "Hello"` instead of erroring out. Also, you can see the rules firing:

```
$ ghc -O -ddump-rule-firings --make rewrite-method.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( rewrite-method.hs, rewrite-method.o )
Rule fired: protect toList
Rule fired: protect fromList
Rule fired: unpack
Rule fired: unpack
Rule fired: protect toList
Rule fired: protect fromList
Rule fired: fromList/toList
Rule fired: unpack
Rule fired: Class op show
Rule fired: >#
Rule fired: tagToEnum#
Rule fired: Class op showsPrec
Rule fired: Class op showList
Rule fired: ++
Rule fired: unpack-list
Rule fired: foldr/app
Rule fired: unpack-list
Rule fired: unpack-list
Linking rewrite-method.exe ...
```