# Type-level Optimizations on function

Tags: haskell

I'm working on [Rasa](https://github.com/ChrisPenner/rasa), my text-editor and I'm doing most of my low-level text manipulation using [Yi.Rope](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yi-rope), but I'd like to expose a nicer interface for people developing extensions. Instead of restricting people to using ropes, strings, or text I figured why not just let people use whatever they want? So I wrote this type-class which allows moving between text-types by using the common denominator of Text:

```
import Control.Lens
import qualified Yi.Rope as Y
import qualified Data.Text as T

class TextLike a where
  toText :: a -> T.Text
  fromText :: T.Text -> a
  asText :: Iso' a T.Text
  asText = iso toText fromText

instance TextLike Y.YiString where
  toText = Y.toText
  fromText = Y.fromText

instance TextLike T.Text where
  toText = id
  fromText = id

instance TextLike [Char] where
  toText = T.pack
  fromText = T.unpack

textConvert :: (TextLike a, TextLike b) => a -> b
textConvert = fromText . toText
```

Now my external api functions can use a constraint like: `myFunc :: TextLike a => a -> ...` constraint and call `textConvert` inside to convert FROM any TextLike TO any TextLike. This actually works quite well, but since my internals use the YiString structure and the intermediary is Text; any time I call a function using this technique I convert from YiString to YiString, but the implementation of textConvert actually goes YiString to Text, then Text back to YiString, which is obviously inefficient :P

I'd love to keep a similar sort of generality (whatever the best way is); but I'd like to optimize certain cases, especially the special case `textConvert :: YiString -> YiString`. Anyone know of a good way? Maybe type level programming, maybe a different approach altogether?

Thanks!

Comment: Avoid tacking on extras to functions precisely because you run into situations like this. Functions are defined once and used in many places. The caller can adapt your function by using, for example, function composition. If you think having a Text interface will be helpful then you can add a module such as `Rasa.Text` which simply wraps your regular API with Text conversion.

Comment: I'm not sure this type class is a good idea, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130011/how-do-you-write-rewrite-rules-for-typeclass-methods) may be useful.

Comment: You should take a look at how it's done in GHC for [`fromIntegral`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.14/base-4.9.0.0/src/GHC-Real.html#fromIntegral)

Comment: If Rasa uses `YiString` everywhere internally, why not make it the core type rather than `Text`, as in `class TextLike a where textLike :: Iso' a YiString`? Then converting internally does no work (other than a very cheap `id`), and presumably the extensions that choose to use other types do no *extra* work since they would have to convert at the extension boundary anyway.

Comment: This is good advice; I'll probably do this, but it's interesting to see how the inlining rules work too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but you should be able to use rewrite rules for this optimization:

```
textConvert :: (TextLike a, TextLike b) => a -> b
textConvert = fromText . toText
{-# INLINE [1] textConvert #-}

{-# RULES
 "toTextY/fromTextY" forall x. textConvert (x :: Y.YiString) = x
 #-}
```

This will effectively replace all inefficient conversions. You can later verify if this rule fires by compiling with `-ddump-rule-firings` flag. Here is a tutorial that goes into all the details on rewrite rules: https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Using_rules