# Rules firing on class methods

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc

My apologies if this is a somewhat vague question, I just want to know I'm heading in the right direction. (GHC 8.0.2)

I've got a "list like" data type, lets call it `T a`. For example it's an instance of `Foldable`, `Functor` and `Monoid`.

There's a few rules I'd like to put into place, for example (roughly speaking, not using exact syntax here):

1. You can fold two lists appended just by folding the first then folding the second (there's no need to actually append the lists):

   foldl' f z (x ++ y) -> foldl' f (foldl' f z x) y
2. If you're folding a list that's been mapped, you can just drag the map function into the fold, eliminating the map:

   foldl' f z (fmap x) -> let h x y = f x (g y) in foldl h z x
3. If you want to map appended lists, just map the individual ones then append them:

   fmap (x ++ y) -> fmap x ++ fmap y

How should I be doing this? What I've currently done is have my instance methods call a top level method, like `fmap'`, which does all the work, and then I've applied the rules to these methods. However `-ddump-rule-rewrites` doesn't seem to show my rules firing, but there are a lot of `Class op *` rules firing, like `Class op fmap` and `Class op foldl'`

Should I be:

a. Doing what I'm doing?
b. Apply my rules on the class methods directly?
c. The standard class rules should cover the situations for my data type, there's no need to do anything? OR
d. Some combination of the above, involving a mixture of `INLINE` and `NOINLINE` pragmas at the appropriate state (please detail).

I suspect the answer is (d), I'd just like some guidance to get started.

Comment: You've got a list like class? Or a list-like data type? If it's an instance of some classes, it's the latter. If those classes are a superclass, it's the first. Also, show some of those rules, and tell us which version of GHC you've used. Depending on what you've done, you might need a finer phase-control.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you write rewrite rules for typeclass methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130011/how-do-you-write-rewrite-rules-for-typeclass-methods)